# How to customize the scrollbar on ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollbar

NOTE: Before you say it's a duplicate and others have solved it and that there are tutorials (like [**this one**](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-vertical-scrollbar-styling/)), I know, but for some reason, they don't work for me.

### Background

I've made a library ([**here**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ListViewVariants)) that shows how to mimic the way that the Contacts app of Lollipop shows the headers on the left.

I'd like to know how to customize the scrollbar and the fast-scroller to look like on Lollipop (either like the contacts app there as I've done [**with RecyclerView**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/LollipopContactsRecyclerViewFastScroller), or like the default one for ListView).

### The problem

For some reason, even though I use the same attributes that are talked about on all of the tutorials and StackOverflow posts, they don't do anything.

Here's the style I created:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" >
  <item name="android:scrollbarFadeDuration">250</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade">300</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarSize">10dip</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal">@drawable/scrollbar_handle_material</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_handle_material</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal">@null</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@null</item>
</style>
```

**res/drawable/scrollbar_handle_material.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#84ffffff"/>
  <size android:width="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

And of course I use it for the ListView:

```
style="@style/CustomTheme"
```

### What I've tried

Well, I tried to play with the attributes, I tried to use a simple ListView (and a GridView, by using the sample "[**DisplayingBitmaps**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DisplayingBitmaps/)") and I tried to set the attributes right in the ListView tag (instead of using a style) as such:

```
            android:scrollbarFadeDuration="250"
            android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="300"
            android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
            android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_handle_material"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_handle_material"
            android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@null"
            android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@null"
```

... but nothing does anything...

### The question

How could it be? what's missing? what's wrong ?

I'd also like to ask if it's possible on Android 2.x.

Comment: can you add `parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView"` to the `CustomTheme` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Tried now. Didn't help. Also, as I've mentioned, I've even tried without declaring a new style, and putting the attributes directly. :(

Comment: can you try on a different device ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I've tried on emulators of multiple versions. Trying on my device is useless as it already has Lollipop 5.1

Answer (score 2):

I came across your question here while looking around. Sure enough, I ran into the same problem (involving custom scrollbars) this week. I came up with a solution, it's not *that* ugly, but on the other hand it's highly customizable and it should work on all devices without layout concerns so that's a plus.

I made an external custom scrollbar container (PC-like, with track background and such) as so:

```
<FrameLayout //for single-child, absolute placement (margin pixels)
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listView" //I placed scrollbar aside my container
    android:id="@+id/scrollbarcontainer"
    android:background="@drawable/scrollbg">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollbar"
        android:src="@drawable/scrollbarthumb"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/> //thumb is stretched to indicate list length
</FrameLayout>
```

And I connected it to an `onScrollListener` on the listView:

```
    findViewById(R.id.listView).setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,int scrollState) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)findViewById(R.id.scrollbar).getLayoutParams();

            //proportional math, will match exactly to default scroll thumb
            double scrlboxh = (double)findViewById(R.id.scrollbarcontainer).getHeight();
            double ttllen = (double)***LIST_LENGTH_IN_PIXELS***;
            double scrlpos = (double)view.getScrollY();
            double boxh = (double)findViewById(R.id.listView).getHeight(); //layout height on screen

            double calc = scrlboxh / (ttllen/boxh);

            params.height = (int)Math.round(calc);

            calc = scrlboxh / (ttllen/scrlpos);

            params.topMargin = (int)Math.round(calc);

            findViewById(R.id.scrollbar).setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount,int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });
```

I used this code in a scrollView, so you will have to calculate your ***list length in pixels***, by whatever means.

To make scrollbar draggable: Add class-wide variable `private double scrollstore = 0;` then:

```
    findViewById(R.id.scrollbar).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    scrollstore = ((FrameLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams()).topMargin - event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                    double thumbpos = event.getRawY()+scrollstore;
                    double scrlboxh = findViewById(R.id.scrollbarcontainer).getHeight();
                    if(thumbpos<0) thumbpos = 0;
                    if(thumbpos>scrlboxh-params.height) thumbpos = scrlboxh-params.height;
                    params.topMargin = (int)Math.round(thumbpos);
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                    double ttllen = (double)***LIST_LENGTH_IN_PIXELS***;
                    double calc = ttllen * (thumbpos/scrlboxh);
                    findViewById(R.id.scrollView).scrollTo(findViewById(R.id.scrollView).getScrollX(),(int)Math.round(calc));
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Happy coding,

Comment: This looks similar to the solution I've found for the RecyclerView (in the library I've written about). Isn't there an official way to customize the scrollbar and fast-scroller? Why didn't the code work as I've written? And, can you please post the dragging-code ?

Comment: Also, do you know perhaps where are the correct resources I should copy from the Android source code, to make it look the same (unless I was right about what I've found) ?

Comment: The XML method is very buggy with complex layouts as people report on here, people say the thumb gets stuck underneath the view and so on... also it's really up to the manufacturer to decide how themes should be displayed (think Samsung and HTC) and I wouldn't rely on those attributes. So basically the "official" way is not reliable.

Comment: The android resource is simply a background color with opacity (I would approximate #000 with 0.5 opacity)

Comment: By "official way", I meant by using the API. About the Android resource, isn't it just what I've found (though for some reason it looks like it's only for the "thumb" and not what's behind it) ?